# Does XCode have a hotkey to go to superclass?

Tags: xcode, hotkeys

Is there a way to do this? I've looked and couldn't find a way. Would make my life a lot easier instead of having to go to the .h file and jumping to the definition of the super class, or clicking the icon to the left of the back button and selecting a superclass.

Answer (score 1):

no it doesn't afaik.. I always go to the header (CTRL+CMD+UP i think) and cmd+click the superclass to open ITS header